# How to export a sub-directory from a bzr branch?

Tags: export, bazaar

[Bazaar User Reference export section](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.0/en/user-reference/index.html#export) contains:

```
Purpose: Export current or past revision to a destination directory or archive.
Usage:   bzr export DEST [BRANCH_OR_SUBDIR]
```

This command:

```
bzr export --format=dir . lp:stevedore
```

Creates the entire tree from the `lp:stevedore` branch without the `.bzr` directory.

Can `export` be used to export just the `src/server` sub-directory from branch `lp:stevedore`?

```
bzr export --format=dir . lp:stevedore/src/server
```

Produces:

```
bzr: ERROR: Permission denied: "Cannot create 'src'. Only Bazaar branches are allowed."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works when exporting a directory from a local branch. I was able to reproduce this and it seems to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/403857